# How to publish open data on my website? (Or: from CSV to RDFa)

Tags: releasing-data, tool-request, csv, rdf, conversion

I already spent some time importing data in a tabular form from a PDF published by an official institution. I would like to publish this table on my website. The data is nicely formatted in CSV.

Is there any simple way to compile it in a ready-to-go RDFa? (Maybe something like an Open Office plugin...) Is there anyone with experience with this kind of workflow?

PS: I am sure it is a problem common to many, but I could hardly find any practical information on the Web.

Comment: What kind of site is it?

Answer (score 13):

If you already have a nicely formatted CSV then why not publish that? You can publish in both formats if you really want to do the RDFa too.

Answer (score 9):

The W3C offers a [collection of tools that convert from CSV to RDF](http://www.w3.org/wiki/ConverterToRdf#CSV_.28Comma-Separated_Values.29). However, there is no explicit mention of RDFa in any of these CSV converters. Personally, I'd give the [RDF Refine plugin](http://refine.deri.ie/) for [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) a try.

Once you have your open data in an RDF format, you could use the [RDF Translator](https://rdf-translator.appspot.com/) to turn it into RDFa.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to publish it on the web, publish it in .html, so it works on the web, aka web platform.

best course of action here is to have .json that you render in .html in the document, but also will render to .csv/.xls//.xlsx/.etc on the fly, for users to download

Comment: Although usually readable by open source tools, MS Excel formats are technically proprietary and therefore not a good format for sharing. But providing options is a great idea.

Comment: yeah that is why i recommended json and html  i also convert to open document format but no americans know what that is, let alone use them. accessibility supercedes proprietary imo if you are providing the data in as many forms as possible

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a common question! First step should consider what your aim and your audience is.

At the ODI we believe that good open data goes beyond technical standards when publishing. That's why we have build the [Open Data Certificates](http://certificate.theodi.org/). More [on the about page](https://certificates.theodi.org/about).

It covers four areas:

1. Legal
2. Technical
3. Practical
4. Social

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other answers but I also think that the first question would be : who is going to use those data ? If it's just for consultation html or csv seems great but if you want them to be re-use by developers, in ways you just don't know yet, maybe RDF gives more flexibility. If your data will just be download by big companies people, .xls or .xlsx will be fine etc...

You really have to wonder who is going to use the data and what for !

cheers